# Matlab textscan gone wrong: cellfun to select data from certain lines

Tags: matlab, textscan

Hi I am using the following code to read some values from lines containing 'GPGGA' from data.txt

```
fid = fopen('D:\data.txt','r');
A=textscan(fid,'%s %*s %f %s %f %s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
Loc = [A{[2, 4]}];
row_idxs = cellfun( @(s) strcmp(s, '$GPGGA'), A{1});
Loc = Loc(row_idxs, :);
display(Loc);
```

The code works perfectly if the last line in data.txt is deleted. Not sure why it throws this error when the last line is included in the text file. What is the reason? I'm confused!

"??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
Error in ==> test at 4
Loc = [A{[2, 4]}];"

data.txt

```
$GPGSV,4,1,16,05,15,046,23,29,47,071,21,16,31,291,18,31,39,202,18*73
$GPGSV,4,1,16,05,15,046,23,29,47,071,21,16,31,291,18,31,39,202,18*73
$GPGSV,4,1,16,05,15,046,23,29,47,071,21,16,31,291,18,31,39,202,18*73
$GPGSV,4,1,16,05,15,046,23,29,47,071,21,16,31,291,18,31,39,202,18*73
$GPGSV,4,2,16,23,13,298,17,25,15,119,17,06,22,247,16,03,04,251,14*75
$GPGSV,4,2,16,23,13,298,17,25,15,119,17,06,22,247,16,03,04,251,14*75
$GPGSV,4,2,16,23,13,298,17,25,15,119,17,06,22,247,16,03,04,251,14*75
$GPGSV,4,2,16,23,13,298,17,25,15,119,17,06,22,247,16,03,04,251,14*75

$GPGGA,1.8,98.90,S,18.0014,E,1,04,1.0,87.8,M,48.0,M,,*76
$GPGGA,1.3,98.91,S,18.0015,E,1,04,1.0,100.7,M,48.0,M,,*40
$GPGGA,1.3,98.92,S,18.0016,E,1,04,1.0,105.4,M,48.0,M,,*4F
$GPGGA,1.8,98.93,S,18.0017,E,1,04,1.0,87.8,M,48.0,M,,*76
$GPGGA,1.8,98.94,S,18.0018,E,1,04,1.0,87.8,M,48.0,M,,*76
$GPGSV,4,4,16,27,,,,26,,,,24,,,,22,,,*79
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If so, then please mark the question answered. Otherwise, let me know if something isn't clear and I can attempt to improve my answer. Thanks.

Comment: it was indeed! Thank you very much! sorry for the laaaaaaaaaate reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string is no good. It is only indicative of 15 columns. The sample data you've posted has 20 columns. I suggest using the following code (which runs without error on my machine) instead:

```
fid = fopen('D:\data.txt','r');
A=textscan(fid,'%s %*s %f %s %f %s %*[^\n]', 'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
Loc = [A{[2, 4]}];
row_idxs = cellfun( @(s) strcmp(s, '$GPGGA'), A{1});
Loc = Loc(row_idxs, :);
display(Loc);
```

Note the construct `%*[^\n]` in my format string. This tells `textscan` to ignore all columns from this point onwards. It is much neater than writing out lots of `%*s` over and over. Also, it means you're less likely to miscount the number of columns when building the format string :-)